# Why is font-family render differently on iOS?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, font-face

I'm using monospace for dollar sign my website, I get the result I'm looking for on chrome / windows and mobile phone but font render different on iOS? Why is the font display different? Is there a way to fix it?

[image: Android chrome web]

[image: iOS web]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful if you provided the CSS code that you are using but I'm guessing you are doing something like this

```
font-family: monospace;
```

The reason this looks different on different operating systems is that "monospace" doesn't actually refer to a particular font it refers to any font where "All glyphs have the same fixed width" so each browser has a different font that it uses for "monospace".

If you would like your font to be consistent across different browsers and operating systems you will need to specify a particular font. This article from MDN explains how to specify font on the web https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts

Answer (score 0):

Chrome font for monospace is consolas , you can check each font using chrome://fonts. Think this might be useful to someone